# Convert JObject to Collection

Tags: json, parsing, json.net

I have the following code:

```
JToken hours = jToken["hours"];
```

It returns the following JSON:

```
{
    "monday": [
        ["11:00", "21:30"]
    ],
    "tuesday": [
        ["11:00", "21:30"]
    ],
    "wednesday": [
        ["11:00", "21:30"]
    ],
    "thursday": [
        ["11:00", "21:30"]
    ],
    "friday": [
        ["11:00", "2:00"]
    ],
    "saturday": [
        ["11:00", "2:00"]
    ],
    "sunday": [
        ["11:00", "21:30"]
    ]
}
```

I need to parse it to typed collection like

```
<string, string>
```

or select a value for any day like

```
hours.Where(p=>p["monday"].Value<string>())
```

I tried:

```
IList<JToken> a = hours.Children().ToList();

var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Pair<string, string>>(hours.Value<string>());

var a = hours["monday"];

hours.Where(p=>p["monday"].Value<string>())
```

no work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This JSON is strange, to say the least. It contains hours in a *list of lists*. One of possible reasons is that the day can contain multiple lists of hours. You should direct this question to the source of the JSON you have.

Anyway, the correct collection type is this:

```
using HoursCollection = Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>>;
```

You can convert a string to this collection using:

```
var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HoursCollection>(hours.ToString());
```

However, a better idea is to use a `JObject` you already have:

```
var a = hours.ToObject<HoursCollection>();
```

You'll be able to get hours for monday from this collection this way:

```
var h = a["monday"].SelectMany(i => i);
```

`SelectMany` is used here to flatten the list of lists.